# protect A transformer from a DC voltage

Tags: transformer

In may project I input a AC voltage to a transformer, the same input may have DC voltage, so i am searching for a way to disconnect the transformer form the circuit ,like a AC detection circuit to make ope of the transformer input open.

The following is a way i just write, i hope we could assets my to improve it or correct it if it is wrong, >> It is the first time i deal with this ICs and i don't know if they works as I suspect or not.

basically i will use a triac form my input to the transformer and i will use a AC voltage logic sensor to detect if my input is dc it will turn the triac on and if a DC voltage applied it will stay off.

As I say, I am not sure if the ICs do the function I required or not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[MID400 datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/695465.pdf)
[MOC3061M datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1688212.pdf)

Mr.Andy aka solution 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just ac couple the input of the transformer to the voltage source. You can do this with a non-polarized capacitor. Depending on the transformer and it's secondary load the capacitor might be 0.1uF to hundreds of microfarads at which point this idea starts to become unfeasible. But please do state what the transformer feeds so this idea can be ruled in or ruled out.

Prevention is better than cure!

Comment: I did not understand you ! is a capacitor will protect the transformer from shorting out my circuit if I input a dc voltage !

Comment: I edit my question and I add what i understand form your post, my input is 230Vrms @5A , and the transformer is step down  230Vrms to15Vrms, my secondary load is just 10 kohm .

Comment: A capacitor blocks DC and lets AC through put simply. With a 10kohm load and 15VAC the power in the load is 22.5 milli watts. This equates to an input current at 230V of about 100 uA. This is a trivial solution for a 1uF 450V capacitor. It will have an impedance at 50Hz of 318 ohms and with 100uA load current plus maybe 50mA magnetization current the capacitor will drop 16 volts meaning the primary of your transformer will receive 214 volts. If it's important it receives closer to 230 volts then a 10uF capacitor will have an impedance of 32 ohms and drop 1.6 volts.

Comment: Having said the above I'm not really sure that your output load is as high as 10kohm so maybe if you rethink this part of my question I asked.

Comment: my AC input is comming from an H bridge and The Active load after the full wave bridge rectifier is a programmable current sink (N channel MOSFET with an op amp).  Also my project is measuring stuff (power current voltage) so i may need to use a 100uF to lose a 0.16V (@2A = 0.32W)